# Проблемы с простеньким шифрованием на C(си)

Tags: c, шифрование

При реализации шифрования было всё отлично, небольшие файлы до 1970 символов шифрует и расшифровывает успешно, но при большом количестве символами > 1970 забивает каким-то мусором.
  После недолгих копаний выяснилось что вся проблема в цикле шифровки буфера, в остальном всё отлично. И сам код собсна:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>

void help_arg();
int convert(char *str);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc == 1){help_arg(); return 0;}

char ch;
int key;
char *in;
FILE *read, *write;
long int size;
char choise;
char *name, *filename;

while((ch=getopt(argc,argv,"hvk:d:e:o:"))!=-1)
{
    switch(ch)
    {
        case 'h':help_arg();return 0;
        case 'v':printf("Kakaya nahui versiya?!Ty chto, ebanulsya?!\n"); return 0;
        case 'e':
        choise='e';
        filename=(char*)optarg;
        break;

        case 'd':
        choise ='d';
        filename=(char*)optarg;
        break;

        case 'k':key=convert(optarg); break;
        case 'o':name=(char*)optarg; break;
        default:help_arg(); return 0;
    }
}
argc-=optind;
argv+=optind;

if((choise == 'e' || choise =='d') && key)
{
        read=fopen(filename,"rb");
        if(read==NULL){printf("Error duiring opening file;\n");return 1;}
        fseek(read,0,SEEK_END);
        size=ftell(read);
        fclose(read);
        in=(char*)malloc(size);
        fread(in,1,size,read);
        printf("%s",in);

    if(choise=='e')
    {
        for(int i=0;i<size-1;++i)
            in[i]=(char)((256+in[i]-key)%256);
    }
    else if(choise=='d')
    {
        for(int i=0;i<size-1;++i)
            in[i]=(char)((256+in[i]+key)%256);
    }


    if(name)
    {   
        write=fopen(name,"wb");
        fwrite(in,1,size,write);
        fclose(write);
        free(in);
    }
    else
    {
        write=fopen("done","wb");
        fwrite(in,1,size,write);
        free(in);
        fclose(write);
    }
}
else help_arg();

return 0;
 }

void help_arg()
{
 printf("Usage: name_programm [-options] <key>\n\t-h \t\t--\tPrint this    menu\n\t-v \t\t--\tPrint version programm\n\t-e <file>\t--\tEncrypting file\n\t-d <file>\t--\tDecrypting file\n\t-k <key>\t--\tKey-word for decript\n\t-o <file>\t--\tName of encripted file(by default name: \"done\")\n");
 }

 int convert(char *str)
 {
  int size=sizeof(str);
  int result=0;
  for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
  {
    result+=(int)str[i];
   }
  return result;
  }
```

Comment: попытайтесь упростить само шифрование! И исправьте все выше перечисленные ошибки

Comment: Само шифрование не сложное, простое смещение символов по таблице аски, вся проблема кроется в записи в буфер

Answer (score 1):

У вас не должно работать вовсе:

```
  fclose(read);
  in=(char*)malloc(size);
  fread(in,1,size,read);
```

Вы ЗАКРЫВАЕТЕ файл, и пытаетесь читать. Понятно, что эта операция ничего не прочитает вообще.

Еще

```
int convert(char *str)
{
   int size=sizeof(str);
```

Здесь `str` - просто указатель, так что `size` - размер указателя, обычно 4 байта (8 на 64-разрадной системе).

Comment: Збавно что читает успешно и как я говорил так же успешно шифрует. Ещё более забавно что шифрует именно в такой редакции. А по поводу указателя - подумаю ещё, спасибо. Просто попробуйте скопипастить код, собрать и попробуйте зашифровать что-рибудь.

Comment: @spacecat Интереса ради скомпилировал (заинтриговало, как вообще может работать чтение из закрытого файла) - сдох даже на файле в 200 байт... VC++ 2017

Comment: Интересно, только что сам попробовал на файле в 331 байт и успешно работает. А что вы имете ввиду под словом "сдох"?

Comment: Выкинуло в консоль какую-то ерунду типа X☺♣ и - "Прекращена работа программы" :) - видимо, обращение по некорректному адресу. Точнее не разбирался. Ну да, ерунда на экране - логично, при выводе `in`, в котором мусор. Ага, слет тоже понятен - у вас `name` не инициализирован, вот и обращение по некорректному адресу...

Comment: Любопытно, вим+gcc успешно скомпилил и работает как и говорил ранее максимум на 1970 байтах).Сейчас перепишу, а то всё же не порядок

Comment: После того, как переписал (обнулил name) - "шифрует", т.е. создает файл с какой-то ерундой, которая при расшифровке остается не меньшим мусором. Чудес не бывает :) Q.E.D.

Comment: Если мусор не повторяется - возможно вы ввели не тот ключик